# System doesnt go to GNU GRUB when restarting, but goes to it when doing cold boot shutdowns

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10

I installed ubuntu 22.04 along side my windows 10. Everytime I press restart buttons from both OS, no boot devices are found so laptop has to shut down and boot again to go to GNU GRUB. This is kind of a hassle since everytime there's an update and the system has to reboot, it wouldnt go to GRUB.

Is this a bug?